# Replacing receptacle wallplate with nightlight, but terminals are not exposed

Tags: receptacle, cover

I went to change the existing wall plate with a wall plate that has a built-in night light when I went to do this I noticed the wiring on the outlet itself is covered by what looks to be a plastic box that covers the wiring on the sides they aren't exposed and they need to be for the night light to work what kind of Outlet is this and what is the plastic box surrounding it how can I get my night light to work?¹ thank you![image][image][image]

Comment: Can you post a pic or part# of the wall plate. The only one I have seen just made contact with the small break-off tabs that are sticking out of the sides of the receptacle..

Comment: Can you get the receptacle out (with the breaker off of course!) and get us photos of its backside please?

Answer (score 3):

This is a cheap outlet that only uses backstabs for connections, no screw terminals. You will need to replace the outlet with one that has screws.
Turn off the power and unscrew the outlet and pull it out of the box. Get a small screwdriver and insert it in the slots in the back of the outlet by each wire while pulling at the wire. The wires should come out. Shepard hook the wires and screw them into the new outlet, black wires to brass screws and white wires to silver screws. You can also pigtail the wires if you have some extra wire and some wire nuts.

Comment: Considering the cheap configuration of receptacle that is a known failure point, broken plastic indicating possible heat damage or other structural damage, paint on contacts, levelling tabs cut off...Even if the nightlight/wallplate just contacts the tabs this receptacle is a good candidate for replacement. Then you have the benefit of inspecting the possible fit of connections before installation of devices.